# Безумное потребление CPU программой при запуске в фоновом режиме.

Tags: background-task, c++, linux

Здравствуйте, возникла следующая проблема.
Имеется написанная на c++ программа. При обычном запуске

```
./someprogram conf.conf > out
```

все работает как надо, но как только я пытаюсь запустить её в фоне

```
./someprogram conf.conf > out &
```

она начинает потреблять неимоверное кол-во CPU (доходило до (!)196%).

Как такое возможно и как с этим бороться?

Comment: Ваш вопрос выглядит примерно так. "У меня который год в подполе происходит подземный стук. Дорогие учёные, скажите, отчего он происходит?"

---
У нас нету исходников программы, и даже если бы они были, думаете, нам бы захотелось анализировать целую программу?

Comment: А зачем вам код? С программой все в порядке, чудеса происходят именно при запуске в фоне.

И каким образом мне проверять её в отладчике если никаких аномалий при обычном запуске не наблюдается?

Comment: А откуда мы знаем, что программа делает, будучи запущенной в фоне? Мы только знаем, что она "в порядке" (внешне), будучи запущенной не в фоне. Вы и вправду думаете, этих данных достаточно, чтобы разобраться в проблеме? (Пошёл протирать хрустальный шар.)

Comment: Давайте дам вам ещё один пример.

> Функция работает нормально, если в качестве входного аргумента передавать 5. А если передавать 7, то крешится. В чём может быть проблема? Вам не нужен код функции, с ней всё в порядке, ведь проблема только при запуске с семёркой. Никаких аномалий при запуске с пятёркой не наблюдается.

Comment: @KoVadim: хм, два потока наперегонки читают stdin?

Comment: KoVadim, браво!

Вы попали в точку, обидно только что не увидел ваш комент до того как разобрался с проблемой.

Проблема крылась тут

    while(1){ 
      int a1; 
      scanf("%d", &a1); 
    }

(таким образом я *демонизировал* свою программу)

добавил usleep(5000) и все заработало как надо.

Выведите свой комментарий в отдельный пост, чтобы я мог выбрать его как правильный ответ.

Comment: @Kenрachi, 

    (таким образом я демонизировал свою программу)
    добавил usleep(5000) и все заработало как надо.

если Вам *кажется*, что заработало как надо, то это не означает, что на самом деле это так.

--

Лучше толком объясните чего именно Вы хотели. Добавлять sleep-ы в цикле - последнее дело.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

с очень большой вероятностью программа пытается что то прочитать с консоли и делает это в цикле. В фоновом режиме ввод не доступен и она бегает в цикле (к тому же код ошибки не проверяется). 196% процентов говорят, что скорее всего у программы два потока, которые бесконечным циклом и грузят.

Comment: Вот [метассылка](http://www.google.com/search?q=psychic+debugging+site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fblogs.msdn.com%2Fb%2Foldnewthing) по теме.

Comment: Где Вы научились такой тонкой настройке хрустального шара? +1

Comment: в детстве. Были хорошие учителя (мама, папа, дедушка и его брат), которые давали правильные задачи и подсовывали правильные книги.